# Get events of a Group with fql api

Tags: facebook, api, events, facebook-fql, facebook-group

I need to display all Facebook events inside a group. I know the group id and the creator id but I am unable to display them.

I always get NULL values in the return, as if they don't exist. How can I get this code to work?

- The group is public
- I want to display the events on a external page even if the user is not logged in so every visitor sees the events of this group.

Code:

```
facebook = new Facebook(
    array('appId' => $this -> params -> get('appid'), 
          'secret' => $this -> params -> get('secret'), 
          'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
         )
    );

// Get the current access token
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$fql = "SELECT name, pic, eid, start_time, end_time, location, description, update_time from event WHERE creator=XXXXXXXXXXX and eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = " . $this -> params -> get('idfbpage') . ")";    

$fqlResult = $facebook -> api($param);
```

Returns null lines, even all the events created by that creator would be OK assuming that they create events ONLY for this group.

Comment: an user-access token is required in order to access this information. how am i supposed to get an access token for the application to the group itself? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with the Graph API?

```
/[group-id]/events
```

I just tried it, and it delivers me all the events from a group, i also get older ones. You can also get the owner of the event easily:

```
/[group-id]/events?fields=owner
```

You can do this with just an app access token, which is created like this:

```
$access_token = FBAPPID . '|' . FBSECRET;
```

If there is a solution with the Graph API, you should always go for it. FQL is a pain.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how can i then build a page with the result of the graph api? the query returns a set of values that i can itherate trough like with a normal sql, but what about the graph api? it returns a page (afaik).. thank you for your help!

Comment: the graph api returns simple json, not a page. see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: i wonder why you started with fql anyway, if you never touched the graph api. usually, you should start with the graph api, and only if there´s really no good solution it´s fql time...

Comment: btw, the most simple graph api call (showing a result already) is your own public profile. you don´t even need an access token for this, just put it in the browser: http://graph.facebook.com/yourvanityurlorfacebookid

Comment: because i am modifying a already existing code! its called SB facebook events plugin. i need to modify it to work for groups, because at the moments its only working for fanpages...

Comment: ok, i think i made some progress, but this requires an advanced access token.. i dont have one.. how am i supposed to get one if the page has to be visibile also for users who are not logged in?? i'm somewhat confused

Comment: well, there is no "advanced access token". before, you did not even have one. there are only app access tokens, page access tokens and user access tokens. in this case (public group) you can just use an app access token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/ - "any valid access_token if the group is public"

i have updated my answer, see above

Comment: thanks for your help, but it doesnt seem to work. i get this error measage: "Uncaught OAuthException: A user access token is required to request this resource. "

Comment: holy cow, just seen that the group isn't public anymore!

Comment: can you tell me the id of the group? it could of course be possible that you cannot just read the events of the group without user permissions, only the group feed and stuff. unfortunately, FQL does not really tell you that ;)

Comment: so basically i am screwed unless they put the group back to public? cant the app simulate that i am logged in since i am in that specific group? the group id is 169492186446800 by the way.. thanks for taking your time and sorry if i gave wrong infos, didnt know about it..

Comment: well, you can use a user access token, but: defaul user access tokens are only valid for 2 hours. you can extend it to 60 days (there is a function for this in the php sdk), but after that you have to refresh the user access token. in any case, this is a very bad solution and i would not do this for non-public groups. kind of makes the non-public status void...